# Copy three element of a dynamic array in another

Tags: c++, arrays

I wanna to ask how to copy three element of a dynamic array in the three last of another

```
vector<int>tab1(i);
vector<int>tab2(j); 
vector<int>tab(i+j);
```

I want to copy more than one element from `tab1` to `tab2`

Comment: And what do you do now? What have you tried? How didn't that work?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're asking, but your question's not very easy to read.

The function below would copy a block of `n` `ints` from `v1`, starting at the position `start`, and add to the end of `v2`

```
void copyN(std::vector<int>& v1, std::vector<int>& v2, unsigned int start, unsigned int n) {
    if (start + n > v1.size()) {
        // handle this bad input
    }
    for (int i = start; i < start + n; i++)
        v2.push_back(v1.at(i));
}
```